# Maven release plugin: Specifying new development version do not affects on pom's custom property

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have following not pretty structured pom:

```
...
<groupId>xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
<version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

...
<properties>
    <xxx.yyy.version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</xxx.yyy.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>aaa</artifactId>
            <version>${xxx.yyy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        ...

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**mvn release:prepare** successfully changes version of pom and value of xxx.yyy.version property to specified in cmd release version(e.g. 0.1) - it is good, ok. After, pugin set-up new development version of project (e.g. 0.2-SNAPSHOT) - thats where I got problem: Value of xxx.yyy.version property remains 0.1. Why xxx.yyy.version property not changes to specified new development version 0.2-SNAPSHOT? How to fix it? Thnx in advance

Comment: I find it hard to understand your question. Are you saying that the maven-release-plugin correctly updates your custom property (`xxx.yyy.version`) from 0.1-SNAPSHOT to 0.1, but fails to update it to 0.2-SNAPSHOT after finishing the release?

Comment: yes, exactly. This is my question

Comment: For me is only changing the third digit (like from 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT to 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT). I wonder if there is way to set a custom next version.

Answer (score 0):

Serious answer: consider using [Maven Version Numbers Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/index.html) instead. I've never heard anything good about Release Plugin (at least, I've heard lots of stories like yours).

Comment: Sounds like sage advice to me at this stage - I am currently fighting the grossly undocumented maven-release-plugin to try and do the same thing. The downvote doesn't seem fair...

Answer (score 0):

make sure updateWorkingCopyVersions parameter isn't sets to be false (default true) in maven-release-plugin configuration.
when this param sets to be false versions wont be incremented